# iPhone game highscore server with OpenFeint

Tags: iphone, openfeint

Im building an iPhone game and would like to implement a fairly simple leaderboard using OpenFeint.

However, I don't really want the full-blown OpenFeint app to reside within my game, rather, I would like to simply use OpenFeint as a datastore and ranking calculator.

Ideally, I'd simply like to display the scores much like Canabalt has done so.

Is it possible to use OpenFeint without all the OpenFeint UI?

Cheers,

Byron

Comment: Are use sure OpenFeint's TOS allows that?

Comment: i guess that needs consideration also. I was intending on displaying the branding etc in the icons and splash screen.

Comment: OF is free for a reason! If you were just leeching off their servers I don't think they'd be too happy. Saying that, there's nothing to stop you doing it: disabling the notifications you don't want, having no dashboard button and just override the achievement / leaderboard notifications for your own custom ones.